# How does Pypresence work, where do I get the Image key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-presence

I recently created an application where I tried to add a Presence (Discord Status) to it...

But how do I get the `Large_Image_Key`, but where do I upload the images

Here's the Script:

```py
RPC = Presence('764214583510433872')
RPC.connect()
RPC.update(state="Using Out-Standing", large_image='outstandinglogo', start=time.time())
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You will have to go to the Discord Developer portal.
   https://discord.com/developers/applications/
2. Create an application.
3. Now you'll will see a client id, if you click on that application.
4. That's your `client_id`.
5. Under application settings, go to **Rich presence >
   [Art Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT9fO.png)**.
6. Now you can add images by clicking on the **Add image** button.

Note: Make sure that your application is not running when uploading images.

7. The name of the image you upload will be your key.
8. Now, you may use this as your `large_image_key`/ `small_image_key`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a URL as long as it isn't a Discord URL

`largeImageKey = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1965106"` will work

`largeImageKey = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/000000000000000000/0000000000000000000/image.png"` will not work